# euclidean tree object stack overflow error even with an exit condition

Tags: java, recursion, processing

I am trying to write a class named Branch in Processing/Java. I have given it an escape condition via global variables, yet it creates too much recursion and a stackoverflow. I am having a hard time understanding why.

```
 int maxIterations = 10;
 int iterations = 0;

class Branch 
{
  //props
  float angle, scale, drawingScale;
 PVector origin, destination;
 //konstrukt
 Branch (float _x, float _y, float _angle, float _scale) {
    origin = new PVector(_x,_y);
    angle = _angle;
    scale = _scale;
    calculateDestination();
    drawMyself();
    rebirth();
  }

  void rebirth() {
    if(iterations < maxIterations) {
      Branch bLeft = new Branch(destination.x,destination.y,angle-50,100);
      Branch bRight = new Branch(destination.x,destination.y,angle+50,100);
      iterations++;
    }
  }

  void calculateDestination() {
    //se till att skala alltid går uppåt.
    scale = abs(scale);
    scale = -scale;
    destination = new PVector(origin.x+angle,origin.y+scale);
  }

  void drawMyself() { 
    drawingScale = scale * -1;
    strokeWeight(10);
    beginShape(LINES);
    vertex(origin.x,origin.y);
    vertex(destination.x, destination.y);
    endShape();

    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(origin.x,origin.y,scale/3,scale/3);
    ellipse(destination.x,destination.y,scale/3,scale/3);

  }


}//End Branch;
```

Any help towards understanding why it overflows or how to effectivly use recursion within an object is very appreiciated!

Comment: If possible, would be good to have more info about the errors that you get, e.g. tracebacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place where you increment iteration is in `rebirth()` after creating two new Branch. The problem is that this incrementation is never reached.

What you have is `rebirth()` calls `Branch()` which calls `rebirth()` which calls `Branch()` etc. and `iterations++` is never executed.

You should probably increment `iterations` before calling `Branch`. Also, use it as a parameter instead of a global variable

Comment: Thank you! Placing the iteration before creating a new Branch did the trick for stopping the overflow.  I see now I have another problem to try to solve, I was hoping creating two new Branches, one with a negative angle and another with a positive would make them always split in two. Yet this is the result of running the code:

http://imgur.com/a/t1oYN

I start the object in program with these parameters: `b1 = new Branch(width/2,height, 0, 100);`

Comment: I solved the problem in my comment above by making iterations a parameter for the Branch. 

Thank you for a very helpful answer :)